# NPM error in parameter 1 scss on run: npm run watch

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack, laravel-mix

This is the error that it shows to me, I put in the *webpack.mix.js*, the parameter 1 of **scss** to list of **scss** I would use in the app:

```
> @ watch /media/ricardo/FILES/projects/Laravel/costurita-etl
> npm run development -- --watch


> @ development /media/ricardo/FILES/projects/Laravel/costurita-etl
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch"

assert.js:49
   throw new AssertionError(obj);
  ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: mix.sass() is missing required parameter 1: src
    at Function.preprocessor (/media/ricardo/FILES/projects/Laravel/costurita-etl/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Verify.js:32:9)
    at Sass.preprocess (/media/ricardo/FILES/projects/Laravel/costurita-etl/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/Preprocessor.js:134:16)
    at Sass.register (/media/ricardo/FILES/projects/Laravel/costurita-etl/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/Sass.js:12:21)
    at Api.mix.(anonymous function).args [as sass] (/media/ricardo/FILES/projects/Laravel/costurita-etl/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/ComponentFactory.js:98:53)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/media/ricardo/FILES/projects/Laravel/costurita-etl/webpack.mix.js:24:2)
    at Module._compile (module.js:649:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:660:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:501:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:493:3)
[The usual npm errors...]
```

This is webpack.mix.js:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.js([
    'resources/assets/js/app.js',
    'resources/assets/js/vague.js',
    'resources/assets/js/freeze_header.js',
    'node_modules/chart.js/src/chart.js',
    'node_modules/jquery/src/jquery.js',
    'node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.js',
    'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',
], 'public/js').sass([
    'resources/assets/sass/app.scss',
    'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
], 'public/css');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `.sass` is a `transpiler` command and not a `combiner` command, which you're treating it like `.js`, and it is not.

Instead, `app.scss` should be the single source of truth for all of it's dependencies, which you can use `@import` to bring those dependencies into your sass file; observe:

```
// app.scss

@import '~bootstrap/scss/src/bootstrap-grid';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/src/bootstrap-reboot';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/src/bootstrap';

// the rest of your code
```

The `~` is a reference to the `node_modules` directory, so you can omit hard coding the path. You also don't need to declare the `.scss` extension here, either.

Finally, you would simply pass the path to your `app.scss` as a string argument to the `.sass` command:

```
.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss')
```

Comment: I only had to replace the **,** for **;**, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

even i got the same error...below code in webpack.mix.js helped me to solve it.

```
mix.react('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```